# Admob interstitial ads not working in ios6

Tags: iphone, ios6, admob

I am using the latest admob SDK(V 6.2.1) for ios. Ads are not shown on ios6 and gives an error `Request Error: No ad to show`.

This happens only on ios 6 even if test mode is set to YES or NO. Ads are working fine on versions lower than ios6. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Are you trying on an iOS6 emulator or device?

Comment: Both. When Testing is set to YES, then ads are showing up on Simulator but on device. When Testing is set to NO, ads are not showing up on both simulator and device.

Answer (score 0):

Test mode doesn't work on iOS 6 devices as per this [forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/test%2420ios%24206/google-admob-ads-sdk/WaW00YBVL6I/fYpukjJBPSoJ).

If you want to get test ads to show up, you will have to use `testDevices` and pass in the ID you get from the AdSupport library (instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/best-practices#testmode)).

If you want to test your ad click flow though I'd take the forum post's suggestion and create a house ad campaign fully allocated to a test publisher ID, and use the test publisher ID into your applications to test.